# Allow by IP access to admin folder with htaccess but allow app script to execute externally

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I'm testing a php / js chat app that has an admin dashboard installed in a public_html root subfolder.

The chatbox is displayed on a separate domain, via embedded javascript.

I've protected the app install with a htaccess file to restrict access to two IP addresses:

```
<Directory /hidedirectory>
 options -Indexes
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xx,xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Directory>
```

However, this stops the app displaying in the users browser unless they are using the allowed IP address.

Could anyone advise on how I could restrict admin access but allow the app to run externally?

Comment: do you have any pattern or specific folder for your admin related routes/pages?
If yes then you can restrict access only on those resources.

Comment: This is not really clear, do you mean your chatbox javascript file loaded externally is situated in a protected admin folder? Then you are talking about an install directory, what does this have to do with the external script or the admin folder you were talking before? Why not simply place public resources in a public folder, and private sections in a private folder?

Comment: I think s/he wants to restrict access of admin dashboard from specific IP addresses, and current solution is application on every portion.

Comment: Hello @GirdhariAgrawal. Thank you for taking the time to look at my question and for your feedback. I shall attempt to only restrict the folder handling the admin. Thank you again.

Comment: Hello @Kaddath. Thank you for your time - I am sorry this was not very clear. Your suggestion of two folders has given me another option to explore. Thank you again.